# How to get the value of a radio button in razor to pass it as a parameter to an action?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

In a view I have two radio buttons:

```
 @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.TipoVP, new String("VP_A".ToCharArray()), new { @checked = "checked" })
 <span class="custom-control-label">Partial View A</span>
 @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.TipoVP, new String("VP_B".ToCharArray()))
 <span class="custom-control-label">Partial View B</span>
```

Action of the controller is like this:

```
 public ActionResult GetVistaParcial(string tipov)
 {
    if (tipov == null || tipov == "VP_A")
       return PartialView("_PartialView_A");
    else
       return PartialView("_PartialView_B");
 }
```

}

And a call to a controller action to load a partial view or another according to the selected radio button

```
 @Html.Action("GetVistaParcial", "miControlador", new { tipov = "the value of checked RadioButton" } )
```

The script for the change event of radio button are:

```
 $("[name=TipoVP]").on('change', function () {
    var $rb = $(this);
    $.ajax({
       url: '/miControlador/GetVistaParcial/',
       data: { tipov: $rb.val() },
       success: function (respuesta) {
          $("#vistaparcial").html(respuesta);
       }
    });
 });
```

How can I pass the value of the radio button checked as a parameter to the action?
It must work when doing the GET and the POST

Comment: could you please show your script to call to `GetVistaParcial`?

Comment: I add the script to the question. thanks

Comment: I'd tried your code on my side and without changing anything it worked as intended. Did you create an object for your model at your get method?

Comment: Yes. But the problem is that when returning from POST the 'tipov' parameter of the 'GetVistaParcial' method is always null. If I launch the POST with the selected partial view B, when I return, partial view A appears.

Comment: But I received `tipov` value either `VP_A` and `VP_B` with respect to radio button clicked in your `GetVistaParcial` action method.

Comment: Yes, that part works correctly. But if you add a button to make a submit of the form, upon returning from the POST and loading the view, the GetVistaParcial () action is called again, and at this point, the value of the parameter is null and therefore, it is always shown the partial view A, even if the rb of view B is selected. tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am wondering if you want go to another page.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GetVistaParcial", "Home"))
{
  @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.TipoVP, new 
     string("VP_A".ToCharArray()), new { @checked = "checked" })
         <span class="custom-control-label">Partial View A</span>

  @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.TipoVP, new 
     String("VP_B".ToCharArray()))
       <span class="custom-control-label">Partial View B</span> 

  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

and you don't need to call this:

```
@Html.Action("GetVistaParcial", "miControlador", new { tipov = "the value of checked RadioButton" } )
```

Your Action should receive the model:

```
public IActionResult GetVistaParcial(YourModel model)
{
   return View();
}
```

Comment: If I try this I get this error when loading the view. `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'`

Comment: You should initialize the value of your model

`public IActionResult Index()
 {
            var myModel= new MyModel();            
            return View(myModel);
        }`

Answer (score 0):

Modify this line data:{ tipov: $rb.val() } to

```
       data: JSON.stringify({ tipov: $rb.val() }),
```

When sending data to a web server, the data has to be a string and JSON.stringify method converts a JavaScript object into a string.

Thanx

Comment: Obaid, this not work for me. When I make the modification, the partial view not change when I click on rb.